# Query where row contains a variable's data

Tags: mysql

Probably easy but I've searched high and low for the answer with no joy.

Say I have this data in a table called 'brand'

```
---------------------------------------
ID    |  brand_name   |  brand_image  |
---------------------------------------
1     |  Sony         | sonypic       |
---------------------------------------
2     |  Samsung      | samsungpic    |
---------------------------------------
3     |  Panasonic    | panapic       |
---------------------------------------
```

I want to select the row from the table where the 'brand_name' appears at the beginning of a variable.

eg. $variable = Sony Walkman

I've done a million queries checking to see if a variable is in a column but never done one checking for a column in a variable. Is it possible?

Comment: "I want to select the row from the table where the 'brand_name' appears at the beginning of a variable. " At the beginning of which "variable"?

Comment: Just a random variable from elsewhere. One of these answers below had nailed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you will use [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php):

```
SELECT * FROM brand WHERE ? LIKE CONCAT(brand_name, '%')
```

Comment: This did the trick, where ? was just a random variable. Many thanks, first time I've posted on StackOverflow and am delighted with rapid and varied responses.

Comment: Actual code: SELECT * FROM brand WHERE '$name' LIKE CONCAT(brand_name, '%')

Answer (score 0):

You can use LIKE. Just snip out the first bit you want to look for:

```
SELECT * FROM brands WHERE brand_name LIKE CONCAT(brand_name, '%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
select * from brand where brand_image like concat(brand_name, '%')
```

?